# I need an azure product that executes my intensive ffmpeg command then dies, and i only get charged for the delta. Any Tips?

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, cloud, scale, cost-management

I need an azure product where i can run my ffmpeg process on but i dont want to deal with acces overhead etc. But i need to be able to specify how strong the cpu and stuff should be.

So consumption functions would be to weak & Premium functions are billed with a fixed rate so i cant use that either

I tried first using a webapi but those are quite costly and because the commands are extremely sudden like in a couple seconds it can go to 100% cpu usage, so scalinng solutions even if i could afford it would be quite hard.

I'm basicly looking for something that i can write a http triggered function for,  i call it, it comes to life executes and then dies.

Ps I'm a novice to Azure so if i overlooked anything obvious please let me know.